# how do I get document viewer to reopen windows

Tags: pantheon, user-interface

One nice thing about Mac OSX is that when you log out and log back in, it will reopen all your windows for you so you can start over where you left off. Chrome will do this for you independently, but I particularly appreciate this capability when it comes to Apple's PDF viewer "Preview." Is there any way to save and restore a set of open documents in Elementary's "Document Viewer" (aka "Evince")?